# Obtain a .eps image usable by psfrag from .pdf (or other format) files

Tags: pdf, eps, psfrag, tiff

I am trying to change some text inside some figures of extension .EPS using the package psfrag. Unfortunately, one of the software which I am using to prepare these figures, the cad CATIA, has not an EPS output (only DXF, PDF, SVG, PS, PNG, JPG, TIFF, etc...). Then, I saved the figure as pdf and I converted the obtained file to EPS using Adobe Acrobat. But psfrag does not seem to work on this final file.

The other software that I am using, SigmaPlot, has an EPS output, however psfrag cannot operate neither on this output. It seems that there are different EPS formats, or codes maybe, and the ones that I get are not usable by psfrag.
I have read a lot of posts on this argument thus excuse me please if this is yet another duplicate of things already explained. I have to confess however that I have not really understood the answers provided, probably because I am a beginner on Latex.

Then, I would like to ask: are there different EPS formats? How can I get the one usable by psfrag? From which file is better to pass, I mean it is better to generate first a PDF and then convert this in EPS, or maybe it is better to have firstly a JPG? How can I obtain the EPS from the firstly-generated file?
Or in alternative, what is the best way to handle this problem in Latex.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you make `psfrag` work at all, i.e. with another EPS file? Maybe first try this, to make sure the error really stems from the other EPS files.

Comment: Your best chance is probably to output to ps and then use ps2eps to add a bounding box (thus creating an eps file). However, it may not work even then. I will add a detailed answer...

Comment: @JasperHabicht, it works with an .eps file I managed to produce using matlab. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, an encapsulated postscript (`eps`) file is a set of geometrical instructions describing how a figure is drawn. If the eps file contains instructions which translate to something like:

> Use this font, put the label 'y=x' here

then `psfrag` can intercept the instruction and change `y=x` to something else.  Spaces around the label can sometimes make trouble, though (see below). However, some `eps` files (notably those exported from Maple) contain geometrical instructions to draw the characaters themselves. The `psfrag` package cannot work in this case.  A third case (the worst of all) is that an `eps` file can contain bitmaps (collections of coloured dots). If the labels are stored in this way, then they can't be replaced by `psfrag`, and they will distort if the figure is resized.

For your CATIA figures, the best approach is to export to postscript (`ps`), and then use `ps2eps` to add a bounding box to the file (this presence/absence of a bounding box is the only difference between postscript and encapsulated postscript). Then try `psfrag` again.

For cases where `psfrag` fails, try opening the file using your favourite text editor, and searching for a label. Let's say you used the label `y=x`. If you are lucky, the postscript code will contain an instruction such as

```
(y=x ) CShow
```

There are many variations of this, but the key point is that you can delete any spaces you find around `y=x` to make `psfrag` work. If you don't find the label anywhere, then either the characters have been drawn individually or they have been bitmapped. Unless you can find an option to change the way in which your figure drawing software exports postscript code, I'm afraid you are then stuck up a well-known creek without a paddle.

Comment: Dear Ian Thompson, unfortunately I am not able to install ps2eps; I downloaded the package from CTAN, but I can't see any .sty or .ins file in there. I leave you the link for reference: https://ctan.org/pkg/ps2eps?lang=en. Thanks.

Comment: @umby --- What platform are you using (Windows/Mac OS/linux)?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: @umby `ps2eps` is a program, not a latex package, but I would concentrate on the main suggestion in this answer, look in the eps file for your label make a test eps with label `xyz`  then look for `(xyz)` in the eps. If it is not there psfrag can not work. If `(x)` and `(y)` and `(z)`  appear then it is writing labels one letter at a time, so use _single letter_ labels and replace using psfrag with real text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my .eps file contains all my labels as I wrote them in the figure, e.g. I wrote volume, and the .eps file contains (volume), and so on.

Comment: oh then normally psfrag will work (make sure you are using latex/dvips not pdflatex)

Comment: @umby if you make a small test eps you could share it using google drive or overleaf or dropbox etc, we could have a look....

Comment: @umby --- You might already have ps2eps. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with how these things work on windows, but you can try opening a dos prompt (or whatever it's called these days) and entering `ps2eps`. Does it recognise the command?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- I forgot about the single letter case. It seems (to me at least) a silly way to insert a label, but great effort has gone into creating applications that generate the worst possible postscript code, so I expect there are some out there that work in precisely this way.

Comment: @IanThompson it is quite common, not least from postscript generated by TeX. You write `Wibble` but the system decides to kern things as it wishes so you end up with `(W)...(i)...(bble)` or whatever with spacing adjustments inserted

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- I stand corrected; it makes sense when kerning is used. I still hate it when figure files do things like this though. It's not quite as annoying as setting the colour and line width for every path when there are 100000 paths for which the settings don't change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this one should be the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16_Smue_MOfsEDhkXde8ciF-LT4L-oKO1/view?usp=sharing, in google drive, thank you.

Comment: @IanThompson, my pc does not recognize ps2eps in the command prompt.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I can't believe it, you were right, it seems that if the labels are composed by just one character the procedure works!! I wanna double check this, I'll take you informed. Unbelievable.

Comment: @umby well we did explicitly document using single letters to avoid this problem over 25 years ago, see `texdoc psfrag` top of page 11

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right it is reported clearly at page 11 of the psfrag documentation. Many thanks!

Comment: @umby --- I'm not sure how to install ps2eps on Windows (primarily because I don't know what else might be missing; on unix/linux systems these things just work). You could try installing ghostscript instead. It can [convert ps files to eps](https://superuser.com/a/1387481).

Comment: Thank you @IanThompson,I will try also this way, however it is good knowing that gostscript can do this conversion, it can be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the answer and the comments:

In Catia, you first save the image as .pdf, then in Adobe you resize and save as .eps, but you need to use single letter labels.

In SigmaPlot, you first export the image as .emf (enhanced metafile), then in Adobe you resize and save as .eps, but you need to use single letter labels. (Unfortunately, psfrag does not seem to recognize labels in an .eps file directly produced by SigmaPlot)

Many thanks to David Carlisle and Ian Thompson.